# Python - User input data type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written the following code in Python 3.x to validate the user's input:

```
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a whole number. Try again.")
```

I know that inputting 'hi' or 'hi46' would be strings (and would cause ValueError).

What data type would inputting ' ' (nothing) be? What about inputting ']%$' (symbols)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using python 3.X, *everything* the user inputs will be a string. Even numbery looking things like "23" or "0". `int(thing)` doesn't validate that `thing` is of the integer type. It attempts to convert `thing` from whatever type it is now, into the integer type, raising a ValueError if it's impossible.

Demonstration:

```
>>> while True:
...     x = input("Enter something: ")
...     print("You entered {}".format(x))
...     print("That object's type is: {}".format(type(x)))
...
Enter something: hi
You entered hi
That object's type is: <class 'str'>
Enter something: hi46
You entered hi46
That object's type is: <class 'str'>
Enter something: 
You entered
That object's type is: <class 'str'>
Enter something: ]%$
You entered ]%$
That object's type is: <class 'str'>
Enter something: 23
You entered 23
That object's type is: <class 'str'>
Enter something: 42
You entered 42
That object's type is: <class 'str'>
Enter something: 0
You entered 0
That object's type is: <class 'str'>
```

Comment: I also corrected my question to clarify that I'm using Python 3.x.

Comment: So can I refer to something like 7.93 as 'a floating point which is considered as/entered as a string'?

Comment: Not really. Saying "<thing> is a floating-point number" in a programming context typically implies "<thing>'s type is `float`", which isn't true for `"7.93"`. The most honest statement would be ' `"7.93"` is a string which `float()` can successfully parse'

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without relying on an exception using isdigit():

```
answer = input("Enter an integer: ")
while not answer.isdigit():
    print("That's not a whole number. Try again.")
    answer = input("Enter an integer: ")
answer = int(answer)
```

isdigit() tests to see if the input string is made up entirely of numbers that can be converted with int().

Comment: Is this more or less efficient?

Comment: You would have to time them to tell, don't forget to add a break into the original to exit the while loop though if you do test them. I've heard that a try/except is a little bit slower than an if, but in this case we've got to call isdigit(). It does follow "Flat is better than nested" for a Pythonic plus. But it also follows the "Look before you leap" philosophy, whereas "Better to ask forgiveness" is considered more Pythonic, which is how the original was written.

Comment: I timed them using iPythons %timeit and a random.choice in place of an input. The original was coming in at 19.6us, whereas this one was coming in at 10.6us. When I disassembled them to bytecode this one was 25 instructions long compared to the originals 29 instructions. So I guess this one is a little bit more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**String**, everything that you `input()` will be a string. And all of them will raise value error except for `C-c` if `int()` raises it.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify what `C-c` is?

Comment: `Ctrl-c` = key board interrupt or any other key combination that indicates End of Input